# Copying table from one SQL server to another SQL server

Tags: mysql

Actually I have a huge amount of data in one Server and I need to copy the same data(entire) into another server. Now I have two options:

1> Create Sql dump from source server and import that dump in destination server.

2> Directly copy the tables from source server to destination server.

Now , I am in problem because either creating dump or direct copying , both will take a huge amount of time. I just want to know which way is more feasible and less time consumption. And what is the easiest(feasible) 'COPY' command in unix for copying from source server to destination server? And I need to copy only tables, not procedures from the Database.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For copy use cp or scp (ssh copy). For table transaction I think the table itself is smaller than the dump but you can try to compress the dump before copying.

But there may be some problems if you copy the table directly if the environment is different

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following link.

http://tech2smooth.blogspot.in/2014/09/want-to-copy-filesdirectories-from-one.html